# error building app bundle: Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig

Tags: android, flutter

I'm getting this error when trying to build the app bundle.I went to line 56 and checked and my line looks like this:
[image]

56. signingConfig signingConfigs.release

and here is error from terminal

`Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
(base) juliapak@julias-MacBook-Pro phonecallforgirls % flutter build appbundle

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/juliapak/Documents/phonecallforgirls/android/app/build.gradle' line: 56
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 737ms
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                      1,400ms
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
(base) juliapak@julias-MacBook-Pro phonecallforgirls %
`

Comment: Can you share your signingConfig property please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this code above **buildTypes** :

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
              keyAlias 'key0'
              keyPassword '************'
              storeFile file('path to your key file')
              storePassword '************'
              v1SigningEnabled true
              v2SigningEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you add this code to the top. How do you get the values for it? And would you add this to the git version control?